# System.FormatException: 'The short switch is not defined in the switch mappings.'

Tags: c#, exception, parameters, formatexception

At this point of my `OnStartup` method… :

```
_host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(e.Args).ConfigureAppConfiguration(c => { c.SetBasePath(appLocation); })
            .ConfigureServices(ConfigureServices).Build();
```

… I get this exception:

[image: 1]

But I don't use short switches and the `-l=de` is just a parameter which is defined in the launch profile. Does anyone know why this exception occurred and how to solve it?

Comment: I still don't know why, but it works for me to remove the `e.Args` from the `CreateDefaultBuilder()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding .net documentation, it only supports 3 styles of arguments:

1. key=value
2. /key value (or /key=value)
3. --key value (or --key=value)

Your argument -l=de (-key=value) is not supported.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#command-line-arguments